# how can I map an int to a corresponding string in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, qt

I have **20 digits** and I would like to associate them with strings.  Is there a faster way besides using a switch case statement to achieve this.

I need to convert an int to a corresponding string and  the numbers aren't necessarily packed. Some code in `Qt` as well might be useful?

Example: The following digits and strings are associated with each other,

```
1:   "Request System Info"

2:   "Change System Info"

10:  "Unkown Error"
```

Comment: Are the numbers contiguous? If so, just use an array/vector of strings.

Comment: I assume "20 numbers", i.e. ints. You'd need Unicode to get more digits than '0'-'9'.

Comment: note: there is no such thing as C/C++

Comment: ... and the answers are all solely for C++. 
I need a C-Implementation and was mislead.. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

easier way to use map

```cpp
std::map<int, std::string> mymap;
mymap[1] = "foo";
mymap[10] = "bar";
// ...
int idx = 10;
std::string lookup = mymap[idx];
```

Comment: and of course the implementation is at liberty to implement map however it likes, including as a switches, jump tables, etc (although it almost certain will be as a binary tree)

Comment: Pm100, the standard mandates some sort of binary tree structure. The standard explicitly forbids jump tables and the like.
Also, while inserting, you will have better performance if you use std::map::insert instead of std::map::operator[].

Comment: One problem with using operator[] to do the lookup is it will modify your map if the index you are looking up is not already in the map.

Answer (score 19):

I recommend std::map<>

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<int, std::string> mapping;

// Initialize the map
mapping.insert(std::make_pair(1, "Request System Info"));
mapping.insert(std::make_pair(2, "Change System Info"));
mapping.insert(std::make_pair(10, "Unkown Error"));

// Use the map
std::map<int, std::string>::const_iterator iter =
    mapping.find(num);
if (iter != mapping.end())
{
    // iter->second contains your string
    // iter->first contains the number you just looked up
}
```

If you have a compiler that implements the [initalizer-list feature of the draft C++0x standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Initializer_lists), you combine your definition and initialization of the map:

```
std::map<int, std::string> mapping = {{1, "Request System Info"},
                                      {2, "Change System Info"}
                                      {10, "Unkown Error"}};
```

std::map<> scales well to a large number of entries as std::map<>::find runs in O(log N).  Once you have the [hash-map feature of the draft C++0x standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Hash_tables), you can easily convert this to a std::unordered_map<> which should be able to look things up in O(1) time.

Comment: is this windows specific programming?

Comment: @yan - std::map is part of the standard C++ library so it will be available with any compliant compiler.

Comment: +1 to the STL map, I was going to suggest it but you beat me to it ;)

Comment: IMO, the insert(make_pair) idiom in this example is harder to read than @pm100's example of mymap[key]=value.  Strictly speaking the insert(make_pair) idiom might be slightly faster since the use of the bracket operator leads to a default constructor invocation, but I wonder if the performance boost is worth the readability benefits.

Comment: Chris, the STL is part of the Standard C++ Library. Netjeff, if the object being copied around is heavyweight (such as std::string), the performance gain of using std::map::insert instead of std::map::operator[] can be substantial. Also, I don't think any C++ programmer is going to look at the calls to map::insert and not know what's going on...

Comment: at this point I think its a question of context and preference.  this will be used for error messages which rarely occur so the performance issue in my case is almost not important. Anyways PM needs the points more than you do ;)

Answer (score 7):

Qt also provides it's own map implementations - [QMap](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmap.html) and [QHash](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qhash.html).

```
QMap<int, QString> myMap;
myMap[1234] = "Some value";
myMap[5678] = "Another value";
```

or

```
myMap.insert(1234, "Some value");
```

The documentation gives more examples but it's very easy to use.

Comment: thx, since I am making a Qt app i will use your approach but my question is a bit more C++ in general so I will have to accept another answer...hope you dont mind (I  wish I could accept 2 answers :D)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for speed, the switch statement will be the most efficient. Most C/C++ compilers will implement it as a binary tree, so it is really fast.

Comment: 20 dense values might end up in a jump table - none of your maps and trees can cope with two jumps...

Comment: also seems simpler to implement

Comment: I was pretty sure a jump table would of been implemented but does that make it less efficient than std::map?

Answer (score 3):

If your strings are known at compile-time, then you can do this in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct message {
    int val;
    const char *msg;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct message messages[] = {
        {1, "Request System Info"},
        {2, "Change System Info"},
        {10, "Unkown Error"}
    };
    size_t nmessages = sizeof messages / sizeof messages[0];
    size_t i;

    for (i=0; i < nmessages; ++i) {
        printf("%d : '%s'\n", messages[i].val, messages[i].msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: actually this is not what I need

Comment: That's not sad, if the number of error codes is small and known at compile time.  Of course, for anything more complicated, this simple scheme will be less than optimal.

Comment: @yan: can you explain more?  I believe that you're building a table of err codes and error messages, right?

Comment: I needed to be able to map the index i that you are using to the message directly i.e. I am receiving a status variable from a function call and I want to insert the associated definition in a message without looking up every time.

Comment: I needed to be able to map the index i that you are using to the message directly i.e. I am receiving a status variable from a function call and I want to insert the associated definition in a message without looking up every time or using a switch statement, STL map worked fine (dont mind him he's a meany).

Answer (score 2):

If your numbers and strings are constant, a map will not work; it has has to be loaded.

For constant numbers and strings, I recommend an array of:

```
struct Entry
{
   unsigned int  key;
   const char *  text;
};
```

And for a large quantity, use a binary search algorithm; otherwise a linear search is about as fast (as long as the array is sorted).

Answer (score 1):

Something like: ?

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
string f(int i)
{
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << i;
    return oss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always loved the switch as a control structure. Simple to understand and maintain. Note that the early `return` short-circuits the need for `break`.

This example tested and working:

```
char* getError(int err){
  switch(err){
    case 1: return "Request System Info";
    case 2: return "Change System Info";
    case 10: return "Unkown Error";
    default: return "Whaaaat!";
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`std::map`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(C%2B%2B))

---

Reading through your question again, I think you're saying that you have only 20 numbers to map (you said 20 digits, which made me think of very large numbers).  If these are all in a fairly small range, you might be better off just using an array.  You need an array of string pointers as large as `largestIndex - smallestIndex + 1`.  Then to get the string associated with a certain number, you'd do something like:

```
std::string GetStatus(int statusID){
    return statusArray[statusID - smallestIndex];
}
```

The `statusArray` variable is initialized with something like:

```
void SetStatus(int statusID, std::string description){
    statusArray[statusID - smallestIndex] = description;
}

void InitStatuses(){
    statusArray = new std::string[largestIndex - smallestIndex + 1];
    SetStatus(1, "Request System Info");
    SetStatus(2, "Change System Info");
    SetStatus(10, "Unknown Error");
}
```

This would be faster than a `map`, and pretty easy to use.  It's just not appropriate if your IDs vary widely.

Answer (score 0):

Are the strings known at compile time?  If so create a map

std::map  messages;

messages[key] = "some value";
messages[key2] = "some other value";

etc

If they're to be read from a file then something like this

```
std::ifstream ifile("the file")

while (ifile && !ifile.eof())
{
  ifile >> key >> value;
  messages[key] = value;
}
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are contiguous (or nearly so), a simple array or vector of strings will work quite nicely.

If there are large gaps between the numbers, chances are that the fastest method will be an array of `std::pair<int, std::string>` (or `std::pair<int, char *>`). While most people automatically think of a binary search for fast lookups, in this case the small number of possibilities to be considered may well allow a linear search to compete quite effectively -- in fact, it may well be the fastest choice available. The reason is simple: while it'll do more comparisons, it avoids things like divisions, and comparisons on 20 ints is going to be fast anyway.

Edit: note that std::map probably is *not* a really good choice. std::map normally uses a balanced binary tree, which means 20 items will use 20 nodes, each of which is normally allocated separately. Each node will typically include at least two pointers in addition to the int you need to store, so you're roughly tripling the amount of data you're storing -- that all adds up to relatively poor cache locality. Given the small number of items involved, one cache miss will cost more than 20 comparisons.